# Why is my "Copy To Clipboard" Button not working?

Tags: javascript, html

Pretty new to Web Programming. I've tried recreating some websites and I wanted to implement a "Copy To Clipboard" Button, but it's not working and I can't figure out why. I've searched through Stackoverflow but I couldn't find an answer to this problem.

Thanks in advance for your help!!

**HTML**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang='en'>    
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <title>Portfolio Homepage</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <div class="left-side">
          <div class="nav-link-wrapper">
            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
          </div>
  
          <div class="nav-link-wrapper active-nav-link">
            <a href="about.html">About</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right-side">
          <div class="brand">
            ptp
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="two-column-wrapper">
          <div class="profile-image-wrapper">
            <img src="images/profile.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="profile-content-wrapper">
            <h1>Managemt and Additional Information</h1>
            <p>This is a student's non-profit project made solemnly for practice and community   involvement. If you have any further inquiry about this project, please contact placeholdermail. </p>
            <p>Thank you very much!</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
function copythis() {
   var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");
   copyText.select(); 
   copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); /*For mobile devices*/

   /* Copy the text inside the text field */
   document.execCommand("copy");

   /* Alert the copied text */
   alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}
```

Comment: Where is your input `myInput`? on HTML
Also, you need to focus the input: 
`textArea.focus();`
`textArea.select();`

Comment: Are you trying to copy a link to the current page the visitor is on?

Answer (score 1):

I see that you have been trying to run the example from [W3school](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_copy_clipboard.asp)

Now, what is wrong in your code :
you have not defined `myInput` in `HTML` so that it can pick up the text from HTML DOM.
Below is the working code.

```js
function myFunction() {
var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");

copyText.select(); 
copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); /*For mobile devices*/

/* Copy the text inside the text field */
document.execCommand("copy");

/* Alert the copied text */
alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
   <head>
      <meta charset='UTF-8'>
      <title>Portfolio Homepage</title>
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container">
         <div class="nav-wrapper">
            <div class="left-side">
               <div class="nav-link-wrapper">
                  <a href="index.html">Home</a>
               </div>
               <div class="nav-link-wrapper active-nav-link">
                  <a href="about.html">About</a>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="right-side">
               <div class="brand">
                  ptp
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="two-column-wrapper">
               <div class="profile-image-wrapper">
                  <img src="images/profile.jpg" alt="">
               </div>
               <div class="profile-content-wrapper">
                  <h1>Managemt and Additional Information</h1>
                  <p>This is a student's non-profit project made solemnly for practice and community   involvement. If you have any further inquiry about this project, please contact placeholdermail.
                     <br>
                     <input type="text" value="Hello World" id="myInput">
                     <button onclick="myFunction()">Copy text</button>
                  </p>
                  <p>Thank you very much!</p>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```